# How can I use Alpha Compositing (Porter and Duff) with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, alphablending

Are there a implementation (API) of Alpha Compositing for .NET. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) means that Windows has a native implementation of it. Of course it can be do with pixel manipulation but this will be a bad performance. If there are a native implementation then we should use it.

If there is no native implementation that can be used from .NET then there is a library that implement it already?

In Java there is a class AlphaComposite and is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows GDI+ does provide some alpha blending.  In .NET, it's exposed by the `Graphics` class, which is quite well documented.  For alpha blending specifically, start with [Alpha Blending Lines and Fills](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3f5k4xc(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is only one of the 12 blending algorithm from Porter and Duff and only if you use a brush. If you want draw an image which has no alpha and you want draw it with an alpha then it is difficult.